# Problem with back button in VideoView

Tags: android, back, android-videoview

I am having difficulty getting the back button to actually finish my activity when pressed. I am running a very simple videoview, using a progressdialog to show loading dialog and onpreparedlistener, etc etc. simple stuff. Anyways, currently when I press the back button, it will just cancel the progressdialog, and leave a black screen, and pressed again, the progressdialog restarts!!! and then when I click the back button again, it displays an alert dialog, "video cannot be played." very annoying. Thanks for your help.

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

    private VideoView mVideoView;

    private static ProgressDialog progressdialog;
    private String path;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview);


        progressdialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", " Video Loading...", true);
        progressdialog.setCancelable(true);

        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        path = b.getString("path");
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));


        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressdialog.dismiss();
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                mVideoView.start();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();

        super.finish();

    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android back button and MediaController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051825/android-back-button-and-mediacontroller)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply write: (No need to create new class for MediaController)

```
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this){
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
                ((Activity) getContext()).finish();

            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It appears that the VideoView consumes the ACTION_DOWN event, and thus ACTION_UP never fires into the dispatchKeyEvent(). This can be easily remedied by returning `false` on the ACTION_DOWN for KEYCODE_BACK instead of calling into the super. (But make sure to allow all other KeyCodes to call into the super!)

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to create a custom MediaController class and override the dispatchKeyEvent function to capture the back KeyEvent and tell the activity to finish.

See [Android back button and MediaController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051825/android-back-button-and-mediacontroller) for more info.

```
public class CustomMediaController extends MediaController {
    public CustomMediaController(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomMediaController(Context context, boolean useFastForward) {
        super(context, useFastForward);
    }

    public CustomMediaController(Context context) {
        super(context, true);
    }

    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
            ((Activity) getContext()).finish();

        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> From CommansWare
>
> Based on the source code, this should work:
>
> 1. Extend MediaController (for the purposes of this answer, call it
>    RonnieMediaController)
> 2. Override dispatchKeyEvent() in RonnieMediaController
> 3. Before chaining to the superclass, check for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK,
>    and if that is encountered, tell your activity to finish()
> 4. Use RonnieMediaController instead of MediaController with your
>    VideoView
>
> Personally, I'd just leave it alone, as with this change your user
> cannot make a RonnieMediaController disappear on demand.

[Here is the link to the original post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051825/android-back-button-and-mediacontroller)

Answer (score -2):

finish() doesn't kill your activity, it just signals to Android that it doesn't need to run the Activity anymore.

I remember solving this by putting "return" in proper places.

Comment: I feel like the issue is that back press is just cancelling the videoview, and the activity is restarting videoview again. I can't seem to override this either...tricky

Comment: That's not a valid statement at all.

Comment: [`finish()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29): "Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via onActivityResult()."

Answer (score -2):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: System.exit() is an anti-pattern on Android.