# Android back button not working while playing video in VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview, back-button, mediacontroller

Android back button is not working while playing the video in VideoView. But it works before playing the video. I am using a custom MediaController for VideoView.
 I tried using **dispatchKeyEvent**, its not working.

Code of Activity that am using VideoView:

```
mc = new CustomMediaController(mVideo.getContext(), screenIcon) {

@Override
public void hide(){
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event){
     if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         super.hide();
         ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
         return true;
     }
     return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
};
```

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
     onBackPressed();
     finish();
   }
   return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
  finish();
}
```

CustomMediaController also contains dispatchKeyEvent:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
   if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
     ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
   }
   return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Also when I scroll the layout, mediaController was not maintaining its position in videoView. To resolve this bug, I've added a code to fix the mediaController position.

```
FrameLayout f;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

         params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mVideo.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = mp.getVideoHeight();
            progress.dismiss();
            f = (FrameLayout) mc.getParent();
            lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, mVideo.getId());
            try {
                ((LinearLayout) f.getParent()).removeView(f);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ((RelativeLayout) f.getParent()).removeView(f);
            }
            ((RelativeLayout) mVideo.getParent()).addView(f, lp);
            //mc.setAnchorView(mVideo);
            mVideo.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Back button works perfect when I remove this above code.

I went through the following questions in stack overflow itself but didn't resolved my issue.

Stack Overflow links I tried:
[Android back button and MediaController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051825/android-back-button-and-mediacontroller)
[Back button won't work when VideoView is playing video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779692/back-button-wont-work-when-videoview-is-playing-video)
[First Back button press not caught when playing a video android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740432/first-back-button-press-not-caught-when-playing-a-video-android)
[Problem with back button in VideoView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207243/problem-with-back-button-in-videoview)

Comment: @NarendraBaratam: I've edited my question. Provided the code also.

Comment: where is your onBackpressed(); in that activity??? Did you override that???

Comment: @NarendraBaratam: ya. I tried onKeyDown & onBackPressed. I tried to finish the activity there.

Comment: you have to release() the media there..and stop()..before call super.onBackPressed() in onBackPressed()

Comment: @NarendraBaratam: Can you tell me the usage ? mVideo.suspend(); ?.
I didn't see release method for videoview. But suspend internally does the release operation I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108363/discussion-between-anooj-krishnan-g-and-narendra-baratam).

Comment: could you resolve this problem ?? i have the same situation

Answer (score 0):

After override the dispatchKeyEvent() in my mediacontroller it works fine

```
 mediaController=new MediaController(this){
        @Override
        public void hide() {
            mediaController.show();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event){
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                super.hide();
                ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
                return true;
            }
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    };

    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
```