# MediaController's default SeekBar not in sync

Tags: android, android-videoview, seekbar, mediacontroller

I am adding a basic video player with VideoView and MediaController.

The SeekBar provided by the MediaController stops at 0:02 min while the video is playing till the end.
I have tried this on 3 different devices with different video lengths.

How to ensure that SeekBar progress and time are in sync with the video?

Here is the relevant code:

VideoPlayerDialog.java

```
videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getContext());

FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
mediaController.setLayoutParams(lp);

((ViewGroup) mediaController.getParent()).removeView(mediaController);
((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoViewWrapper)).addView(mediaController);

videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(imageUri);
videoView.requestFocus();
```

dialog_image_preview.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black87">

    <uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/photo_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/videoViewWrapper"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="30dp">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoplayer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_button_material"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer. On your MediaController constructor, override it's `hide()` void and use `this.show()` in it so the MediaController shows when it hides.
The reason for this, is because MediaController automatically hides itself after 3 seconds by default, even with `show(0)`. So, if you force the MediaController to be shown, it will still act as if it's hiding after 3 seconds (seekbar stops syncing, play/pause button not updating). Overriding the `hide()` void to show the MediaController combats this.

You can also create a custom class that extends MediaPlayer to ovverride `hide()` as well.

Example code:

```
final MediaController mediaController =  new MediaController(context){
    @Override
    public void hide() {
        this.show();
    }
};
```

Comment: This looks like a good answer. However I found another way around using this code. Cannot test the answer myself. If someone confirms I will mark this as correct answer.

Comment: @HarishVishwakarma - what was your other way around? You can always post as a comment.

Comment: I tested it and it really works!! but the issue is I played video in dialog and after pressing back button it freezes the screen, and if I remove this line video dialog closes perfectly fine and no issue with back press also but then seekbar stops after 2 sec

Comment: @AnshulKhare It's been awhile but you can try to create a subclass of MediaController, add a field `private bool shouldSync = false;`, add both a getter and a setter for `shouldSync`, then override `hide` and write `if (shouldSync) show();`.
Now you can do `mMediaCtrl.setShouldSync(true);` on dialog open and `mMediaCtrl.setShouldSync(false);` on dialog close.

Answer (score 0):

You could try connecting automatically the media controller to the Video View with

`MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
                                   mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                                   videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. It just hides the playback controls below videoview but no changes with seekbar updates.

Answer (score 0):

Followed reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442678/android-back-button-not-working-while-playing-video-in-videoview), I was able to resolve issue of seekbar which was stopping after 2 seconds and back press issue on which the screen was getting freeze.

I used dispatchkeyevent to detect back press and showed media controller after the start of video.

```
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener { mp ->

        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE

        mc = object : MediaController(mContext) {

            override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent): Boolean {

                if (event.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    super.hide()//Hide mediaController
                    scoreDialog.dismiss()//Close this dialog/activity

                    return true//If press Back button, finish here
                }
                //If not Back button, other button work as usual.
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
            }

        }
        videoView.setMediaController(mc)
        mc.setAnchorView(videoView)

        (mc.parent as ViewGroup).removeView(mc)

        (scoreDialog.findViewById(R.id.videoViewWrapper) as FrameLayout).addView(mc)
        
        mp.start()
        mc.show(0)
    }
```