# Handling back button VideoView on Android Pie

Tags: android, android-videoview, onbackpressed, android-9.0-pie

I'm using `VideoView` with `MediaController`. I'm fighting with back-press bug, which is common and on SO we can find a lot of topics about that:

[Android back button and MediaController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051825/android-back-button-and-mediacontroller)

[Back button won't work when VideoView is playing video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779692/back-button-wont-work-when-videoview-is-playing-video)

[First Back button press not caught when playing a video android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740432/first-back-button-press-not-caught-when-playing-a-video-android)

[Problem with back button in VideoView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207243/problem-with-back-button-in-videoview)

all of these are suggesting overriding `dispatchKeyEvent` inside `MediaController`. But it won't fire on Android Pie... Method works on older OS versions, but on Pie I'm not getting a `dispatchKeyEvent` or `onKeyPressed` call anywhere when media controls are visible - `Activity` (`onBackPressed` also checked), any `View` including `VideoView` (has focus during whole runtime) and `MediaController`. In fact as long as `MediaController` is visible on screen the back button isn't working (isn't closing `Activity` nor hidding `MediaController`) and I can't figure out "who" consumes that event...

```
MediaController mp = new MediaController(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    onBackPressed();
                return true;
            }
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    };
videoView.setMediaController(mp);
```

when I remove above code everything works fine, but I need these media controls

someone had a similar problem year ago, without any answer... (note that Pie is younger...)

[Android back button not working while playing video in VideoView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442678/android-back-button-not-working-while-playing-video-in-videoview)

Comment: Having the same issue - have you found a solution?

Comment: sadly no... I've ended with X button in top-left corner. I'm considering replacing `VideoView` with ExoPlayer, maybe this will help, but currently I have more important tasks to do. But still: this will not resolve `VideoView`-`MediaConstroller`-pair issue...

Comment: Have the same issue. I assume dispatchKeyEvent must be getting events because the MediaController buttons still work in Pie, yet when I override it in a sub-class, no events are ever received...

Answer (score 2):

I was also searching for a solution until i found it by myself:

In your MediaController you have to add an OnUnhandledKeyEventListener.

```
 public bool OnUnhandledKeyEvent(View v, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Back && e.Action == KeyEventActions.Up)
        {
            ...
        }
        return true;
    }
```

For me (using Xamarin) it looks like:

```
public class ExtMediaController : MediaController
{
    public delegate void CallBackButtonDelegate();
    public CallBackButtonDelegate BackEvent;
    public ExtMediaController(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        base.AddOnUnhandledKeyEventListener(new OnUnhandledKeyEventListener(this));
    }


    public override bool DispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Back)
        {
            BackEvent?.Invoke();
            //return base.DispatchKeyEvent(e);
        }  

        return base.DispatchKeyEvent(e);
    }

}


 public class OnUnhandledKeyEventListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
{
    private ExtMediaController LinkedMediaController;

    public OnUnhandledKeyEventListener(ExtMediaController extMediaController)
    {
        LinkedMediaController = extMediaController;
    }

    public bool OnUnhandledKeyEvent(View v, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Back && e.Action == KeyEventActions.Up)
        {
            LinkedMediaController.BackEvent?.Invoke();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. I am testing it on Android 11

Answer (score 2):

I extended the mediacontroller class so that it can handle the activity-backpressed properly for all versions of android (including android P). You can instantiate this class as a media controller.

```
public class ExtendedMediaController extends MediaController {
private Activity            mParentActivity;

public ExtendedMediaController(Context context, Activity parentActivity) {
    super(context);
    mParentActivity = parentActivity;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        OnUnhandledKeyEventListener eventListener = new OnUnhandledKeyEventListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onUnhandledKeyEvent(View v, KeyEvent event) {
                boolean fHandled = false;

                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        fHandled =  true;
                    } else if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        if(mParentActivity != null) {
                            mParentActivity.onBackPressed();
                            fHandled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return(fHandled);
            }
        };
        addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener(eventListener);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    boolean fHandled = false;
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            fHandled =  true;
        } else if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            mParentActivity.onBackPressed();
            fHandled = true;
        }
    }
    if(!fHandled) {
        fHandled = super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
    return(fHandled);
}


}
```