# Back button won't work when VideoView is playing video

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I have a `VideoView` in one of my `Activities` and if I try to press the back `Button` it doesn't take me to the previous `Activity` and it doesn't give any error messages in the log cat either.

I have tried overriding the `onBackPressed()` method and I have tried calling the prev `Activity` using an `Intent`, but even then the back `Button` didn't do anything.

This problem only occurs when the video is playing and even after it is finished playing. The only time the back `Button` works is before the video starts playing. My `VideoView` also has a `MediaController` set to it.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android back button and MediaController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051825/android-back-button-and-mediacontroller)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From CommansWare
>
> Based on the source code, this should work:
>
> 1. Extend MediaController (for the purposes of this answer, call it
>    RonnieMediaController)
> 2. Override dispatchKeyEvent() in RonnieMediaController
> 3. Before chaining to the superclass, check for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK,
>    and if that is encountered, tell your activity to finish()
> 4. Use RonnieMediaController instead of MediaController with your
>    VideoView
>
> Personally, I'd just leave it alone, as with this change your user
> cannot make a RonnieMediaController disappear on demand.

[Here is the link to the original post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051825/android-back-button-and-mediacontroller)

Comment: No problem. Be sure to go to that post i linked and vote it up. =)