# Android unable to go back to the previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, onbackpressed

I'm working in news feed like activity which contain list view. The list view contains multiple videos, When i click the video view i open another activity and play the video in fullscreen mode. When i back pressed the activity cannot move to previous activity which contain listview.

> when i pressed back button the same activity loads it doesn't go to
>   previous activity

*Even i try*

```
finish()
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

But no use....

Following codes are i have used

**ListviewActivity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VideoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("VideoURL", MY_VIDEO_URL);
startActivity(intent);
```

**VideoActivity**

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

VideoView videoSurface;
ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.video_activity);

    ToastMsg.displayShortToastMsg("CREATE");
    String videoUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("VideoURL");

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading Please Wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

    videoSurface = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);

    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                VideoActivity.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoSurface);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri video = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
        videoSurface.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoSurface.setVideoURI(video);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    videoSurface.requestFocus();
    videoSurface.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            videoSurface.start();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
   }
}
```

**My Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:uses-implied-permission="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-
auto"
package="com.stage.lookara"
android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission 
 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:name=".app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Social">
    <activity
        android:name=".DashBoard"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" 
/>
            <data android:host="www.youtube.com" 
android:mimeType="text/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsPage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Search"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LookaraNotification"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.SocialActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.Comment"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.ReplyComment"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.SinglePost"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.Profile"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.FriendProfileView"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.Friends"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.IndividualChat"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.Photos"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.AlbumViewer"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.VideoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".social.Event"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.JournalActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.SocialEditEvents"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.SocialFollowers"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.SingleEvent"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.Message"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.GalleryView"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.Channel"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.MyChannel"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.ChannelCreateForm"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.ChannelMembers"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.ReportDetails"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.InvitesList"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.OtherUserChannelList"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.ChannelProfilePage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.Ask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.AskPost"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.Journal"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PreviewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.ChatMessages"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" />f
    <activity
        android:name=".social.CreateSocial"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".social.OtherUserFriends"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".professinal.ProfessionalSearch"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".professinal.ProfessionalActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".professinal.CreateProfessional"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".professinal.ProfessionalFollowers"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".professinal.ProfessionalJournals"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".professinal.ProfessionalConnections"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".professinal.FindProfessional"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".professinal.ProfessionalMessage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".professinal.ProfessionalProfile"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".common.Reviews"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".bussiness.BusinessActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".bussiness.BusinessSearch"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".bussiness.Partners"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".bussiness.BusinessSettings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".bussiness.CreateBusiness"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".bussiness.BusinessFollowers"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".bussiness.BusinessJournals"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".bussiness.BusinessList"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".bussiness.BusinessMessage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".bussiness.BusinessProfile"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".bussiness.BusinessOverView"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".bussiness.BusinessSpecialOffer"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".bussiness.ContactDetails"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden
|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" 
/>
    <activity

android:name="com.darsh.multipleimageselect.
activities.AlbumSelectActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MultipleImageSelectTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" 
/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/FB_APP_ID" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action 
android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action 
android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".common.LookaraService" />
    <service android:name=".common.LookaraUploadService" />


 </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please check AndroidManifest whether is there any launchMode for the activities and is there any android:noHistory="true"

Comment: no i 'm not used android:noHistory="true" any where in manifest

Comment: post ur manifest..

Comment: i used android:noHistory="true"  on in login activity

Comment: your MainActivity class contains the list of videos? if it is then make sure you have not override the onBackPressed there and if overriden then that should be correct.

Comment: moreover i would like to say that read about fragment in android.

Comment: @Ankush Bist but im not using fragment

Comment: Remove the onBackPressed() method from your Video activity..

Comment: @Mahesh even i removed onBackPressed() doesn't Work

Comment: @Swathy post the activity code where this re-load is running.

Comment: @ Ankush Bist  i press back button in VideoActivity, then again the VideoActivity loads instead of go back to my parent activity

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding the following into manifest.

```
   <activity
    android:name=". VideoActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value=".MainActivity"/>
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
videoSurface.setMediaController(new MediaController(this){
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event){

        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
            finish();
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: i used this but not work yet the videoactivity loads again and again when i pressed back

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have added meta-data

```
    <activity
        android:name=".VideoActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="YOUR_PAKAGE_NAME.VideoListActivity" />
    </activity>
```

for your VideoActivity in Manifest file.

Comment: i used this but not work yet the videoactivity loads again and again when i pressed back

Answer (score 0):

`VideoView` may consumes the `ACTION_DOWN` event, and thus KEYCODE_BACK  never fires into the `dispatchKeyEvent().`

From [Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051825/android-back-button-and-mediacontroller)

use this code in your activity:

```
videoSurface.setMediaController(new MediaController(this){
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
            ((Activity) getContext()).finish();   //finish current activity

        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
});
```